# <time> attribute HTML

Tags: html, time

```
<p>The dentist's office opens at <time>8:00</time>.</p>

<p>The dentist's office opens at 8:00.</p>
```

Why is the time tag needed if both of these paragraphs tags display the same thing? This might be a total noob question, but I'm working a neat project.

Test:

The dentist's office opens at 8:00.

The dentist's office opens at 8:00.

Comment: The time tag is not used for direct "visual" purposes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

Comment: The time element does not render as anything special in any of the major browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp

Comment: The description from mdn: 
This can be helpful for user agents to offer any event scheduling for user's calendar.

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer never trust w3schools. Full of errors. Reference MDN instead.

Comment: Note: Stack Overflow does not support `<time>` tag in question yet. It will be stripped away automatically.

Comment: @Raptor Thank you! Last question, if it only displays time why would I uses a "<time>PT10S</time>" syntax.

Comment: You shouldn't use `<time>` tag for parsing time strings.

Answer (score 6):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) says:

> This element is intended to be used presenting dates and times in a
>   machine readable format. **This can be helpful for user agents to
>   offer any event scheduling for user's calendar.**

It is not used for any visual purpose. You can use CSS for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a semantical tag.
Not really useful without any post-processing, but the more your HTML is semantically tagged, the more it will be easily processable.

EDIT : found this https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element. There're some examples and use cases.